# RabbitMQ publish a message with REST API

Tags: c#, python, rabbitmq

I have an application written in Python (PIKA) and C# (official NuGet package). Those applications are publishing new messages into RabbitMQ queues.

Until now, I used this syntax to publish a new message into the queue:

```
model.BasicPublish(exchange, routingKey, basicProperties, body);
```

I found that `BasicPublish` function always returns with success. I also read in RabbitMQ documentation that in case of broker destroyed, the messages that didn't send yet will be removed without sending it to RabbitMQ.

I want to avoid the loss of messages. So, I found 3 options to submit those messages to publish:

1. Transaction - Very slow.
2. Confirmation - I found it tricky to implement in a multi-threaded environment.
3. with REST API - What do you think about that?

I think that it will be ideal for me yo use REST API for inserting messages into queues.

### The Question:

The way that I found to send a message with API is to send POST message to this endpoint:

```
http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/vhost/amq.default/publish
```

As you can see, this port (15672) belongs to the RabbitMQ management system.

1. Is this the right way to use RabbitMQ with REST API?
2. Can I trust the RabbitMQ management system in the production environment?
3. Can you recommend an alternative to REST API that will accept to message enqueue immediately after insertion (blocking)?

Comment: You cannot do high throughput with the REST API , i would strongly recommend to use Publisher Confirm which is the second option outlined by you . Implementation should not be complicated , give it a shot and if something does not work , stackoverflow is there for rescue :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, don't use the HTTP API. It is not intended for production use for publishing or consuming messages.

You **must** use publisher confirms. The technique described in [this tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-seven-java.html) applies to the .NET client library as well.

You could also investigate libraries written on top of the official .NET library that may correctly implement publisher confirms for you. [EasyNetQ](http://easynetq.com/) is one such library.

Another good resource to read with concern to 100% reliability is [this blog post](https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2018/9/10/how-to-lose-messages-on-a-rabbitmq-cluster).